# imported app data via email - I can't access the data

Tags: iphone, ios

I have nearly configured my iPhone App to be able to import and export data via email. So far I am able to export files with the extension .qm2 (this my own extension i configured in my app Plist) and import files. The data I'm using to export is NSData. All is working fine but I am unable to populate an array when the data is imported in.
The method I chose to import is as follows in my AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url
{

NSString *URLString = [url absoluteString];
NSData *dataReceived = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:URLString];
NSArray *newArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:dataReceived];

 NSLog(@"%@",newArray);
 // logs out null;
return YES;
}
```

The data is there because if I NSLog the URLString it prints our the following: URLString = file://localhost/private/var/mobile/Applications/A3615B4E-388F-4986-ACD0-B564DBB7D265/Documents/Inbox/test%201-16.qmf. Again my problem is how do get the imported data and put it in a NSArray?

Comment: first of all why don't you use `NSData *dataReceived = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];`. and also can you see anything in the data you just created?

Comment: Well done! just changed the method to ..contentsOfUrl:url and dataReceived filled up. What was I thinking with my URLString and contentsOfFile method !! thanks again.